# SeekBarPreference is deprecated?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-preferences, preferencescreen, seekbarpreference

I was searching and i saw only old examples of SeekBarPreference and i tried do it in XML but intelsense don't detect it or if I do ctrl+space or other things don't show.

So I went to check Android developers and I went in this [site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) and in the left side, on Classes you don't see SeekBarPreference so I want to know if it is deprecated or something to replace that.

Answer (score 1):

yah i remember that one.  Now you can  extend preference and create your own seekbar.  there is alot of 3rd party libraries to get this done:

I personally use this one but there is alot out there just google:

[sliderpreference](https://github.com/jayschwa/AndroidSliderPreference)

Comment: Thanks I used the SeekBarPreference  of android and it show pretty like what you showed you have to try this like i tried `<SeekBarPreference
            android:defaultValue="22"
            android:title="Set the default time"
            android:key="seekBar"
            android:max="100"
            /> `

And it works like what you putted and its not 3rd party.

Comment: @TiagoSousa If you use <SeekBarPreference then there will be padding on all sides. Were you able to remove that padding. I have tried negative padding too but in vain.

Comment: @LokeshKumar I already resolved that but it was a long time ago, and now I don't know what I did, but thanks.